# Do Gmail and Google Inbox support universal links in March 2016?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

Back in October 2015, Gmail and Google Inbox [did not support universal links](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/):

> Note that Gmail and Google Inbox apps do not handle Universal Links properly (they will not open the apps). It’s not possible to open any app by any universal link in their apps.

Does Gmail and Google Inbox on iOS now support Universal Links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom webview Google uses still appears to interfere with the Universal Links detection mechanism, so **no, as of March 2016 Universal Links do not work with Gmail and Google Inbox**.

Comment: **New info:** I just ran a test with a universal link. **Now the links work** with recent versions of Inbox and Gmail. (Gmail 5.0.170326, Inbox 1.3.170326)

Comment: Do you have an example of a URL pattern that will open the Gmail app? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @JustinKrause I don't. That's a private undocumented URI scheme, not designed to be used this way. This questions was about OUTGOING links, rather than INCOMING links.